# QueryResponse (SolrJ 5.0.0) returns ClassCastException from String to NamedList for spellcheck.collation=true

Tags: solr, solrj

We used the Solr and we would like to get `SpellCheck.collate` from Solr by using SolrJ.

```
  SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery(q);
   query.add("spellcheck", "on");
   query.add(SpellingParams.SPELLCHECK_Q, q);
   query.add(SpellingParams.SPELLCHECK_COUNT, "5");
   query.add(SpellingParams.SPELLCHECK_ALTERNATIVE_TERM_COUNT, "2");
   query.add(SpellingParams.SPELLCHECK_MAX_RESULTS_FOR_SUGGEST, "5");
   query.add(SpellingParams.SPELLCHECK_COLLATE, "true");
   query.add(SpellingParams.SPELLCHECK_BUILD, "true");
   query.set(SpellingParams.SPELLCHECK_COLLATE_EXTENDED_RESULTS, true);
   query.set(SpellingParams.SPELLCHECK_MAX_COLLATIONS, 2);
```

When we tried with the Solr Admin GUI, the spellcheck and collation return correctly, but when we call query from QueryResponse object, it returns error

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to org.apache.solr.common.util.NamedList

The snippet is as follow

```
QueryResponse rsp = new QueryResponse();
    try {
        rsp = server.query(query);
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

It looks like it could not parse from the string to `namedList` from the Spellcheck entries.

PS. when we remove the `spellcheck.collate=true`, the spellcheck is working normally(but w/o collate) and there is no casting error.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: I'm late to the party, but most likely you've been hit by https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3029 - you'll see this if solrj is v4 and solr is v5 and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your spellchecker configuration in `solrconfig.xml`, I'm going to have to make some educated guesses here.

First of all, I think you might want to use `SolrQuery`'s `set()` method, but I'm not 100% sure if that's available in your version of SolrJ. For example, here's how I set my spellchecker query:

```
        // Set the spellcheck
        solrQuery.set("spellcheck", Boolean.TRUE);

        // Set the spellcheck_q parameter
        solrQuery.set(SpellingParams.SPELLCHECK_Q, searchTerm);
```

If the `set()` method isn't available, I wouldn't worry about it too much at this point.

Second, when you're setting the `spellcheck` attribute, you want to use `true`, not "on".

If none of that helps, post your spellchecker config from `solrconfig.xml` and I might be able to help a bit more.

For what it's worth, I copy-pasted your code into my current Solr (5.2.1) unit tests and could not reproduce the error.

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar issue and I found solution by setting these

```
SpellingParams.SPELLCHECK_COLLATE_EXTENDED_RESULTS=false
```

This way only the collation query is returned. I didn't need hits and misspell suggestions.